# How would I use variables whose value is determined at later stage in Angular?

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I have an array in my component whose values get initialized asynchronously and later I want to use that array in template.

This is the snippet from service:

```js
let array = [];
processDataFromStore(): void {
   this.store.select(...)
   .subscribe(data => {
      if (some_cond) {
         array.push(data);
      }
   });
}

getArrayValue() {
   return this.array;
}
```

In my component I am trying to access value of array as:

```js
array = [];
ngOnInit() {
   this.service.processDataFromStore();
   this.array = this.service.getArrayValue(); // this is always empty value
}
```

And using this in template

```html
<div *ngIf="array.length > 0">
   <!-- This condition is always false -->
</div>
```

I need help in restructing code such that array value will get initialized and accessible in template. I tried two approaches but both of them gave me error: **Expression Changed after it has been checked**

Approach 1: Wrap initialization statement within `setTimeOut()`

```js
setTimeOut(()=> {
   this.array = this.service.getArrayValue();
}, 1000);
```

Approach 2: Create a temporary observable in service that returns `true` when data is initialized

```js
// service
processDataFromStore(): void {
   ...
   this.behaviorSubject.next(true);
}

// component
this.service.behaviorSubject.subscribe(...
   this.array = this.service.getArrayValue();
);
```

Comment: One option is to make the service expose an observable *of the data*, then use the Async pipe to resolve it in the template. Rather than `array.push(data)` (mutating the existing array), it would be more like `arraySubject.next([...array, data])` (creating and sharing a new array).

Comment: As @jonrsharpe mentioed, it's a best approch. Check this link for more clarity https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-async-pipe-in-angular-8